# gin ShouldBind When a large request payload, waste a lot of cpu

Tags: go

<kbd>gin ShouldBind When a large request payload，will waste a lot of cpu, this is whether there is an optimization method</kbd>

```
func getQueryArgument(ctx *gin.Context) (QueryArgument, error) {
    query := QueryArgument{}
    query.Limit = conf.GetEnv().QueryDefaultLimit
    if err := ctx.ShouldBind(&query); err != nil {
        return QueryArgument{}, err
    }
    return query, nil
}
```

<kbd>I expect large payloads to need to be optimized</kbd>